# How to keep track of things in asp.net.mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a small web application and I need help tracking states.

This application ask few questions to a user in a random manner (one at a time). But, to do so, I need to know which question already been answered (so I don't repeat any questions) and if the user got it right or not.

I need to know if the user got the last question right because, if he awnsers wrong, the application will ask a random question from a different list.

To do so, I created this class "state" in the controller which is supposed to keep track of things.

```
    public class state
    {
        public string via { get; set; }

        public string previousQuestionList { get; set; }
        public string currentQuestionList { get; set; }

        public string leftButton { get; set; }
        public string rightButton { get; set; }

        public List<Question> previousQuestions { get; set; }
        public Question currentQuestion { get; set; }

        public bool lastAnswer { get; set; }
    }
```

So, when the user enters the page for the first time, the controller send a default information to the view and it constructs the page.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        state currentState = new state();
        currentState.currentQuestion = new Question();
        currentState.currentQuestion.description = "Qual a via do seu cartão?";
        currentState.currentQuestion.aplicabilidade = true;
        currentState.leftButton = "1a Via";
        currentState.rightButton = "2a Via";
        return View(currentState);
    }
```

And the view looks like this:

[image: View]

The html code is something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sistema de Script de Desbloqueio";
}

@model Sistema_de_Script_de_Desbloqueio.Controllers.HomeController.state


<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>@Model.currentQuestion.description</h1>
</div>

<form name="Formulário" action="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" method="post">

    @if (Model.currentQuestion.aplicabilidade == true)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>@Model.leftButton</h2></div>          
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="btn btn-warning btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>@Model.rightButton</h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn btn-primary btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>@Model.leftButton</h2></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn btn-warning btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>@Model.rightButton</h2></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>N/A</h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

My idea is that the user press one of the buttons and send the object of the class "state" (model) back along with the information of which button was pressed to the controller.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you considered using `Session` to maintain state?

Comment: IMHO, in addition to the previous comment on good old `Sessions`, another way is to enlist the _client_ in "state" persistence (e.g. [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) ).

Comment: I'll look into Session and Web Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the tip from "elolos" and used "Session" to maintain the date and worked just fine.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    state currentState = new state();

    //Some code here

    Session["currentState"] = currentState

    return View(currentState);
}
```

And then in the "Post" method I retrieved the information from "currentState"

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string lastButton)
    {
        state currentState = Session["currentState"] as state;

        //Some code here

        return View(currentState);
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to perform simple `Postback` or `AJAX POST` from view you are creating.

Add property for last button clicked to model:

```
public string LastClickedButton { get; set; }
```

Then add ActionResult to POST to:

```
public ActionResult IndexPost(state postedState)
{
      //Do stuff.
}
```

And perform POST from view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sistema de Script de Desbloqueio";
}

@model Sistema_de_Script_de_Desbloqueio.Controllers.HomeController.state


<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>@Model.currentQuestion.description</h1>
</div>

<form name="Formulário" action="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" method="post">

    @if (Model.currentQuestion.aplicabilidade == true)
    {
        <div class="row">
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("IndexPost", "Home"))
        {
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="btn btn-primary btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>@Model.leftButton</h2></div>
            </div>
            @Html.Hidden("LastClickedButton", @Model.leftButton);
        }
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("IndexPost", "Home"))
        {
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-group-justified" role="group" type="submit"><h2>@Model.rightButton</h2></div>
            </button>
            @Html.Hidden("LastClickedButton", @Model.rightButton);
        }
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-group-justified" role="group" type="submit"><h2>@Model.leftButton</h2></button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn btn-warning btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>@Model.rightButton</h2></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="btn btn-default btn-group-justified" role="group"><h2>N/A</h2></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

Downright of this is that you need to send all the information you received, so many redundant `@Html.Hidden`/`@Html.HiddenFor` will be produced.
Another way round this is you can change Controller action to:

```
public ActionResult IndexPost(state postedState, string clickedButton)
{
      //Do anything you need with clickedButton
}
```

And post clickedButton via `route`:

```
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("IndexPost", "Home", new { clickedButton = @Model.rightButton }))
        {
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-group-justified" role="group" type="submit"><h2>@Model.rightButton</h2></div>
            </button>
        }
```

Comment: By doing what you told I'm automatically sending all the "state" object back to the controller?

Comment: I'm afraid the whole state needs to be set in manually for example: `HiddenFor(m => m.PropertyName)` for each property so that it gets posted back to the controller. Otherwise it will be null. Of course you might want to send only information that you're gonna need now.